# Google Maps with categories

Tags: plugins, google-maps

i'm looking for plugin that could help me make multiple markers on google maps and multiple categories.
This plugin would be great but i need better Categories manager. For example

1. |Restaurant
2. |--Vegetarian
3. |--Vegan
4. |Hotels
5. |--5-star
6. |--4-star

Also i need ability to chose which categories map will show. 
Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

[Mapsmarker](http://www.mapsmarker.com/docs/features/) looks pretty robust. On their feature list page they state that you can organize your markers in layers, so maybe that work for categories. I have not used it.

I have used [Mappress](http://wphostreviews.com/product/mappress) which allows you to add custom markers and you can create different maps on different pages if you want to categorize them like that.